# Magento 2 not loading css/js after pointing domain to new location

Tags: magento2

I originally had Magento 1 at `example.com` which my webhost had in `/public_html/example`

I installed Magento 2 at `v2.example.com` which my webhost had pointed at `/public_html/example2`

After migration, I am attempting to switch the Magento 2 shop to be located at the old shop's domain.

- I've set webhost to point `example.com` to `public_html/example2`
- I've changed the corresponding values in `core_config_data's` `web_*_ur`l both to `example.com` instead of `v2.example.co`m.
- I also changed the cookie domain setting accordingly.
- I've cleaned caches and deleted /var/cache content.

When attempting to load example.com, the browser attempts to load

```
http://example.com/example/index.php/?SID= . . .
```

The title of the page is 404 and it loads some of the front page content but without css styling or js.

Also, when attempting to access the backend, http://example.com/index.php/admin takes me to http://example.com/index.php/admin/example.com/index.php/admin/?SID= . . .

What have I forgotten to do?

Comment: It is simply example.com. I tried with a trailing forwardslash but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be putting wrong url in your **`core_config_data`** table **path** column/field.
Lets edit `web/secure/base_url` path clumn value to `http://example.com/`

It should be like http://example.com/ means start with **`http://`** an end with **`/`**

Hope above will resolve your issue.